# What's the reverse of Math Power (**) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I was wondering how to get the inverse of power in Ruby?

```
2 ** 4 # => 16
```

and then I would like to get the inverse of it, and I'm not sure which operator to use

```
16 ?? 2 # => 4
```

Comment: To get simple square root, just use Ruby's `Math.sqrt(16) # => 4.0` - you get a float because a square root is not always an integer. If you definitely want/expect an integer, cast the result to an int with `Math.sqrt(16).to_i`. which will round the result **down** to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The inverse of exponentiation is the logarithm. If `ab = c`, then `logac = b`.

You can find logarithm functions in the [`Math`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Math.html) module, specifically `log()` for base-*e* and `log10()` for base-10.

To get a logarithm to a *different* base (say `n`), use the formula `logNa = logxa/logxN`, where `x` is a value such as *e* or 10.

For your *specific* case:

> `log216
>     =   loge16/loge2
>     =   Math.log(16) / Math.log(2)
>     =   4`

Whether you consider the explanation good because it expands your knowledge, or bad because you hated high school math, is entirely up to you :-)

Comment: Ha, thanks a lot paxdiablo this was a very good explanation, and yes you're right I used to hate it, but now I can see that I've missed a lot because of that, cheers!

Answer (score 6):

```
Math.log(16) / Math.log(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to obtain the logarithm, starting with Ruby 1.9.1, would be to use `Math.log2`:

```
[1] pry(main)> Math.log2(2**4)
=> 4.0
```